# How to Find Next String After the Needle Using Strpos()

Tags: php, strpos

I'm using PHP `strpos()` to find a needle in a paragraph of text.  I'm struggling with how to find the next word *after* the needle is found.

For example, consider the following paragraph.

```
$description = "Hello, this is a test paragraph.  The SCREENSHOT mysite.com/screenshot.jpg and the LINK mysite.com/link.html is what I want to return.";
```

I can use `strpos($description, "SCREENSHOT")` to detect if SCREENSHOT exists, but I want to get the link after SCREENSHOT, namely `mysite.com/screenshot.jpg`.  In a similar fashion, I want to detect if the description contains LINK and then return `mysite.com/link.html`.

How can I use `strpos()` and then return the following word?  I'm assuming this might be done with a RegEx, but I'm not sure.  The next word would be "a space after the needle, followed by anything, followed by a space".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or the "old" way... :-)

```
$word = "SCREENSHOT ";
$pos = strpos($description, $word);
if($pos!==false){
    $link = substr($description, $pos+strlen($word));
    $link = substr($link, strpos($link, " "));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a single regular expression:

```
if (preg_match_all('/(SCREENSHOT|LINK) (\S+?)/', $description, $matches)) {
    $needles = $matches[1]; // The words SCREENSHOT and LINK, if you need them
    $links = $matches[2]; // Contains the screenshot and/or link URLs
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a little testing on my site using the following:

```
$description = "Hello, this is a test paragraph. The SCREENSHOT mysite.com/screenshot.jpg and the LINK mysite.com/link.html is what I want to return.";

$matches = array();
preg_match('/(?<=SCREENSHOT\s)[^\s]*/', $description, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
echo '<br />';
preg_match('/(?<=LINK\s)[^\s]*/', $description, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

I'm using positive lookbehind to get what you want.

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the replies!  Both of these work, I get to choose which one I go with.  :)  String functions and RegEx are not my strong suit!