# Catch a variable string after a prefined needle with strpos()

Tags: php, strpos

I have a tricky problem to solve. I already got a push in the right direction by this question and answers: [How to Find Next String After the Needle Using Strpos()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866968/how-to-find-next-string-after-the-needle-using-strpos)

But my problem is a bit more tricky.

This is the context:

Users enter an amount in a comment field by entering a predefined term ('amount'), followed by the number. This is a free field, so I need to take into account the various ways in which users enter the amount. With or without currency indicator, decimals, etc.

Example:

```
$commentfield = "2011-7-5 Send bid. Amount: € 3482,- Also included Lease option";
```

or, another example:

```
$commentfield = "2011-6-5 Bid accepted. Amount: 235. Client requested quick delivery";
```

Now, I need to extract that amount to be able to sum it. Is there anyone who can push me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Trying to process monetary transactions based off of free-form text fields is bound to end in tears.

Comment: You can use preg_match() function of php assuming that the number after the Amount will be the value to be extracted.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh: the problem is that the "number" (which is actually a number and an optional currency marker) comes from a free-form field. So it may in fact just say "I like pancakes". It may also say "500 bitcoins". Or perhaps "three score and twelve francs" There's no defined currency, and no enforced format. It's a mess to say the least.

Comment: @chris sorry i dint think that much.. i just thought of an option to extract the amount. i thought it will be a number.

Comment: Luckily I can guarantee that the number entered behind the word 'amount' is in Euro and that if there's no number, there's nothing that needs extracting. But I'd have to agree that it's a mess ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) using PHP function
[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).
You will need to get a list of all possible formats people already use for the amounts.

Going forward, you might want to make amount a separate field all together.

Comment: "You will need to get a list of all possible formats people already use for the amounts" -- except that in a free-form text field people can abuse numbers pretty easily. Like "30.000" (American decimal, reduces to 30.00 -- valid, could be confused with a European field seperator which is "30,000" American -- big difference) and "25+5" (annoying, but valid). It's much much easier (and less ambiguous) to enforce formatting upon the user so that there's no confusion about what "happened" to the number they entered.

Comment: I was going in this direction to make it as easy as possible for the users, but the objections Chris raised made me turn around completely. They'll simply have to fill in an extra field. Thanks Chris, Brady and mithunsatheesh!

Comment: Making things easier for the user is a fallacy I see a lot of developers fall into. There's a tendency to think that if you make the user think less, they'll be more likely to have an easy time with the software. It's actually quite the opposite. Most people like structure (and instructions) because they've been trained to see data the way computers do. So seeing a totally free-form text field that says "amount" is basically like saying, "haha, now what?" I know for me personally every time I see something like that my frustration level goes up, not down. Good decision.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be useful.

```
$s ="2011-7-5 Send bid. Amount: € 3482,- Also included Lease option";
preg_match('/amount(\s*):(\s*)€(\s*)(?P<price>\d+)/i',$s,$match);
echo $match['price'];
```