# Separate each word into a Array

Tags: php

I have a file with contents like :

Apple 100

banana 200

Cat 300

I want to search for a particular string in the file and get the next word. Eg: I search for cat, I get 300. I have looked up this solution: [How to Find Next String After the Needle Using Strpos()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866968/how-to-find-next-string-after-the-needle-using-strpos), but that didn't help and I didn't get the expected output. I would be glad if you can suggest any method without using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best approach, but with the data you've provided, it'll work.

1. Get the contents of the file with [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)
2. Separate the values into array elements with [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
3. Iterate over your array and check each element's index as odd or even. Copy to new array.

Not perfect, but on the right track.

```
<?php
$filename = 'data.txt'; // Let's assume this is the file you mentioned
$handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$clean = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $contents));
$flat_elems = explode(' ', $clean);

$ii = count($flat_elems);
for ($i = 0; $i < $ii; $i++) {
    if ($i%2<1) $multi[$flat_elems[$i]] = $flat_elems[$i+1];
}

print_r($multi);
```

This outputs a multidimensional array like this:

```
Array
(
    [Apple] => 100
    [banana] => 200
    [Cat] => 300
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it doesn't use regex, but it will be inefficient if the string you're searching is longer:

```
function get_next_word($string, $preceding_word)
{
  // Turns the string into an array by splitting on spaces
  $words_as_array = explode(' ', $string); 

  // Search the array of words for the word before the word we want to return
  if (($position = array_search($preceding_word, $words_as_array)) !== FALSE)
    return $words_as_array[$position + 1]; // Returns the next word
  else
    return false; // Could not find word
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$find = 'Apple';
preg_match_all('/' . $find . '\s(\d+)/', $content, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: second item of matched array returns count of searched product

Answer (score 0):

You might benefit from using named regex subpatterns to capture the information you're looking for.

For example you, finding a number the word that is its former (1 <= value <= 9999)

```
/*String to search*/
$str = "cat 300";
/*String to find*/
$find = "cat";
/*Search for value*/
preg_match("/^$find+\s*+(?P<value>[0-9]{1,4})$/", $str, $r);
/*Print results*/
print_r($r);
```

In cases where a match is found the results array will contain the number you're looking for indexed as 'value'.

This approach can be combined with

```
file_get_contents($file);
```